# Is there a YAML validator that includes imported GitLab CI YAML files?

Tags: yaml

Hey I am looking for a YAML validator to verify my .yaml files are correct.
I am using GitLab CI.
Since I have a massive configuration I split it to several yaml files and import them on my main yaml file (using gitlab's CI syntax for import `.yml` files)

For example in `main.yml` I have:

```
include:
    - ".imported_config1.yml"
    - ".imported_config2.yml"
```

There are many `yaml` validators online, but none seem to validate it with the imports and it takes time and effort to manually copy paste all the imports to a different file and validate it just for the validation process...

When I run GitLab CI it verifies the `.yaml` correctly, but I am looking for an external tool to perform only the validation process before the config file is in the server.

Is there any tool or fix for this?

Comment: You may want to add more context to the question: this is a GitLab CI configuration and whether you have tried the pipeline editor or the VS Code extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, there is no standard mechanism in YAML to import/include other files (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437697) on SO and associated discussion). So, you will either need to follow a standard format that already provides this, such as OpenAPI's [`$ref`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/), or use a validator that has a proper handler for this `include` node.

Looking through the linked discussion on SO, there seems to be a way to use inheritance via the Ruby Gem [yaml_extend](https://github.com/magynhard/yaml_extend) and [PyYAML](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml) [can support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577670) something like `!include` which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer!
The `include` infrastructure I use is Gitlab CI's.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/
I want to have an external validator that can handle that...

Comment: @Orb I could not verify this, but the documentation says the pipeline editor should be capable of verifying this and also, there is a VS Code extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitLab.gitlab-workflow#validate-gitlab-ci-configuration - Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the notes mate. I edited the question. 
GitLab CI does verify it although I am looking for an  external tool to perform the check before the files are in the server (e.g. using pre-commit hook).  I use VS2015 and not VScode although the extension you mentioned seem to have what I am looking for.. I saw that there is an extension for VS I will check it out.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MysticBoy.GitLabExtensionforVisualStudio&ssr=false#overview